# Is there a specific order for <label for="" type="" ...></label>?

Tags: html, css

I have some questions:

1. If you type something like this `<label type="" id="" name="">`, is there a specific order that **needs to be adhered to** when it comes to `type`, `id`, `name`, `etc`, or is considered *best practice* to just follow the examples shown on let's say W3Schools?
2. What's the difference between commenting using `<!-- some comment -->` and `/* some comment */`? I (think I) observed that both sometimes work in either a HTML *and* a CSS document

Comment: If you want to follow the best practices, you should visit [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a document in GitHub that outlines a reasonable style guide for HTML development.
I suggest you read it.
https://github.com/necolas/idiomatic-html

1. HTML attributes should be listed in an order that reflects the fact that class names are the primary interface through which CSS and JavaScript select elements.

- class
- id
- data-*
- Everything else

Example:

```
<a class="[value]" id="[value]" data-name="[value]" href="[url]">[text]</a>
```

2. About comments:

`<!-- some comment -->` is a HTML comment.

`/* comment */`
is a CSS and JavaScript comment.

**In short: Have a style!**

Comment: Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

About your first question, you can use a name or id or both. you don't have to use all of them or even one of them.
About your second question, this comment -  for Html, and this comment - /* some comment */ for the CSS. If you try those comments in other files, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

1. There is no specific order for the HTML tag attributes, i.e. you can add it in any order, as long as all required attributes are added.
2. `<!-- some comment -->` is HTML comment, `/* some comment */` is CSS and JS comment (and some other languages as well, such as Swift and Objective-C).

Answer (score 1):

## First question, The answer is No.

No you don't need a specific order to set properties of a HTML element, you can do this

```html
<label class="someClass" id="someID"></label>
```

Or

```html
<label id="someID" class="someClass"></label>
```

the order of attributes of a HTML element doesn't matter, but order of the HTML element itself does matter.

For Example:

This HTML Code:

```html
<label for="firstName">First Name: </label>
<input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName">
```

Shouldn't/Can't Be Written as this:

```html
<input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName">
<label for="firstName">First Name: </label>
```

## Second question

this Syntax `<!-- Comment -->` is used in only HTML Documents

whereas this Syntax `/* Comment */` is used in only CSS Documents

But this doesn't mean you can't use this syntax in HTML `/* Comment */`, for example inside of `style` tag in HTML, you can directly write CSS inside your HTML Document you can use the CSS Comment Syntax

For Example:

```html
<style>
  /* This is a CSS Comment */
  h1 { background-color: #ccc; }
</style>
<h1>Hey There Brother!</h1>
```

Or you can use the CSS Comment Syntax in the `style` attribute of a HTML Element.

For Example

```html
<h1 style="background-color: #ccc; /* This is a CSS Comment */">Hey There Brother!</h1>
```

But you can't use HTML Comment Syntax inside of CSS, there might be an exception which i don't know but as far as i know you can't.

Comment: Thank you so much :)